# Конструктор копирования...

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, можете на пальцах объяснить, зачем нужен конструктор копирования?
Не совсем ясен его смысл. (

Answer (score 5):

Конструктор копирования нужен, чтобы создать копию объекта, причем безопасно. 
Иногда может сгодится побитовая копия, но в большинстве случаев она не подходит,
например когда объект владеет какими-то ресурсами, которые освобождаются в деструкторе.
Например если написать такой код:

```
struct A {
    A(int a) { ptr = new int(a); }
    ~A() { delete ptr; }
    A(const A& obj) { ptr = obj.ptr; }
    int* ptr;
};

A obj1(10);
A obj2 = obj1;
```

то один и тот же указатель освободится сначала в деструкторе объекта obj1, а затем в деструкторе объекта obj2, что приведет к ошибке. Правильнее было бы сделать конструктор копирования такой:

```
A(const A& obj) { ptr = new int(*obj.ptr); }
```

Тогда каждый объект будет располагать своим уникальным указателем.

Comment: obj является указателем?

Answer (score 2):

Что бы создать новый объект на основе существующего, тем самым автоматически инициализировав новый объект данными из того, на основе которого делается копия.